# How to rewrite an URL to a specific controller class with htaccess file in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have 2 controller classes in my application named Localhost/electronics.

The URL `"Localhost/electronics/cameras"` goes to

```
"localhost/electronics/home/details/cameras".
```

This is happening because of the rule

```
$route['(:any)'] = "home/details/$1";
```

2nd controller class `specifics()` and it's method `showspecifics()` is accessed through URL

```
`"localhost/electronics/specifics/showspecifics/camera1.`
```

**How can I do the following?**

Only with the help `.HTaccess` file, I want to.. be able to access the second class `specifics()` using URL

```
`"localhost/electronics/camera1` .
```

I am aware that using

```
`$route['(controllername/:any)'] = "specifics/showspecifics/$1";`
```

is a possible way close to achieving the clean URL but it's not what I want.

Please advise as to how to use htaccess to accomplish this.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would capture the final part of the URL and then rewrite the request, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/electronics/specifics/showspecifics/
RewriteRule ^electronics/(.+)$ /electronics/specifics/showspecifics/$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` is there to prevent a rewrite loop.

This doesn't work with CodeIgniter however, because CodeIgniter looks at `REQUEST_URI` to determine the controller and method to serve this request. But `REQUEST_URI` isn't changed by the `RewriteRule` and remains `/electronics/camera1`, and CodeIgniter doesn't find an appropriate controller.

To change `REQUEST_URI`, you had to redirect instead of rewrite, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^electronics/(.+)$ /electronics/specifics/showspecifics/$1 [R,L]
```

but this also changes the client's URL bar, which isn't desired in this case.

So, there's no way to achieve this with .htaccess and CodeIgniter.

---

To do this in CodeIgniter, you would use appropriate routes in `application/config/routes.php` like

```
$route['(cameras|smartphones|computers)'] = 'home/details/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'specifics/showspecifics/$1';
```

This handles the few categories by controller and method `home/details`, and everything else by the controller and method `specifics/showspecifics`.

Comment: Hi Olaf. in "RewriteRule ^electronics/cameras$ - [L]" cameras is the argument that is dynamically created and there would be many of them. I suppose I should replace "cameras$" with first controller class name. Am I right?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot Olaf. I am trying everything to resolve this issue as it determines my employment now. Please be informed that "electronics" is the name of the application folder(root folder).

Comment: I have made changes but the routing seems to be handled by codeigniter route only. Htaccess appears not to do its jobs. Can't see why not.

Comment: I go with RewriteRule ^electronics/(computer|smartphones|cameras)$ - [L] as I have less than 10 categories. But I believe there is something I fail to get right.

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite? Does it work at all? Can you redirect everything to somewhere else, maybe try `RewriteRule ^(electronics/details/.*) http://www.google.com/?q=$1 [R,L]` as the first rule

Comment: 'RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]'

Comment: The above htaccess code I used to remove index.php from the URL which is working perfect. So mod_rewrite must be enabled.

Comment: Ok, then this is not the reason. Are these rules before or after the new rules? When these are the first rules, then they handle everything, before the other rules are even considered.

Comment: New rules are after the old rules.

Comment: Then move the new rules to the beginning. See also the updated answer because of `RewriteCond`.

Comment: I did as advised, still not working. Could I ask you if you can access my computer via teamviewer at your free time to try yourself. I apologize if this request violates the terms of Stackoverflow.

Comment: It is too easy to mess up something, so I won't do that. Maybe I will find the time to setup a test environment and find a solution. But this won't be right now, because I will be away for a while.

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I found your excellent professional data online and I immediately wrote an email to your email webmaster@olafdietsche.de. I couldn't believe a drop out could have made such an unbelievable professional success. Thanks again.

Comment: After going through all your comments again and again I found the solution largely with the help of your knowledge. Thanks a lot. I am sure people working with codeigniter experiencing similar problems will benefit from this question and answers as you have well explained the process. Thanks a lot Olaf.